# Android GoogleApiClient is deprecated to get the list of suggested contacts

Tags: java, android, kotlin, google-api, google-api-client

Currently, my application is using GoogleApiClient to display a list of suggested contacts from the user's Google account. For some good reason that *API is now deprecated*.

I have tried using Google REST API `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly` & `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.phonenumbers.read`. Neither of these responses with a contact number.

I have also referred enough SO questions and blogs, nothing has yet proven helpful. If you have any workaround or working example on this, drop your thoughts below.

*I think Google has stopped providing contact detail of a user due to security issues.*

Comment: Which request are you making, please include your code.  Have you considered using the google api java client?